# How to call user defind function in myysql python code?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to search for data encrypted as described in the following code

```
query = "SELECT Month,Utility_Number,Name FROM smart_data WHERE clean_embedefunction(Name) like '%{}%';".format( SCKHAindexName)
```

but it can not retrieve anything and this is the function implementation

```
 def clean_embede(encrypt):
  word = ''
   for i, v in enumerate(encrypt):
      if i % (3 + 1) == 0: continue
      word += v
 return word
```

Comment: Did you try the query outside python?

Comment: I cant, because i wrote the clean_embedefunction implementation inside pycharm enviroment

Comment: you can't do that, so implement the function in mysql

Comment: I can not because i run on cloud server

Comment: I want to get data from the server and apply clean_embede function on it to retrieve according to the condition

Comment: You can't call Python functions from SQL. If you can't implement the function in MySQL, you'll have to select everything and then filter in Python.

Comment: `i % (3 + 1)` can be written more simply as `i % 4`

Comment: then you need to pull all data and run  the function and comparison in python

Answer (score 0):

It seems very unlikely that your cloud provider does not allow creation of [UDFs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html). Who is your provider?

My Python skills are non-existant, but I am pretty sure this is equivalent to your Python function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION `clean_embede`(encrypt VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE word VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE i SMALLINT DEFAULT 0;

    WHILE i < CHAR_LENGTH(encrypt) DO
        IF (i % 4) <> 0 THEN
            SET word = CONCAT(word, MID(encrypt, i + 1, 1));
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN word;
END
```

And then in your query:

```
WHERE clean_embede(Name) like '%{}%';
```

If you really cannot add a UDF, as all it is doing is removing every fourth character starting at 0, you could tackle it from the other side by inserting `_` ([underscore](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like:%7E:text=_%20matches%20exactly%20one%20character)) in your search string. So, if the search string is `abcdefghi`, it becomes:

```
WHERE Name like '%abc_def_ghi%';
```

Comment: when I tried to run this code  

 gives me error #1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Comment: When I turn on log_bin_trust_function_creators, it gives me access denied

Comment: Check your provider's documentation. Some have _"special"_ ways of setting server variables.

Comment: https://www.clever-cloud.com/   that is provider's

Comment: It looks like it is a shared hosting model so you are probably out of luck. You could try raising a support ticket to ask them. Alternatively, you can resort to my other suggestion of modifying the string passed to `LIKE`.